# fetch inverse entities in many-to-many unidirectionnal relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, relationship

I have 2 entities, ActivityType and ActivityNature, with a Many-to-Many unidirectionnal relationship, where ActivityType is the owning Entity :

```
<?php

namespace Evo\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ActivityType
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_activity_types")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Evo\AppBundle\Entity\ActivityTypeRepository")
 */
class ActivityType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Evo\AppBundle\Entity\ActivityNature")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sf_activity_types_natures")
     */
    protected $activityNatures;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

```
namespace Evo\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ActivityNature
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sf_activity_natures")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Evo\AppBundle\Entity\ActivityNatureRepository")
 */
class ActivityNature implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

I can easily fetch activityNatures related to a given activityType with $activityType->getActivityNatures();
But I can't find any clue on how to fetch activityTypes from a given activityNature. I'd really like not to set a bi-directionnal relation because of performance issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following dql:

```
"SELECT at FROM AcmeBundle:ActivityType at WHERE :natureId MEMEBR OF at.activityNatures"
```

---

**EDIT:** answer to your comment, get ActivityNature:

```
"SELECT an FROM AcmeBundle:ActivityType at JOIN at.activityNatures an WHERE at.id = :activitiTypeId"
```

Comment: Ok cool, didn't find anything about this "MEMBER OF" thing. And now, what kind of DQL should I use if I want to fetch the ActivityNature from a given activityType, without using $activityType->getActivityNatures() ?

Comment: search `MEMBER OF` in this [document](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)